# regexp - monetary string match with decimals and thousand seperators

Tags: php, regex

```
/(?<!\d[- ]|[\d.,])-?[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:(?:[., ]\d{3})*|\d*)(?![\d%]|[- ][\d%])/
```

subject

```
812,30
48 kdk 1
54%
1.393.434 test
2.392,39
2,292.39
```

I don't want to match any amount with decimals. So the lines `812,30`, `2.392,39` and `2,292.39` should not match.

https://regex101.com/r/XPgypx/2

Comment: No sure what you are asking here?

Comment: Check the link.. I don't want to match the first and last line

Comment: maybe ask the question? do you want to exclude all numbers separated by , or just some?

Comment: So just match lines that don't contain commas?

Comment: have updated the question.. I dont want to match numbers with decimals.. neither `.` nor `,`

Comment: How can both of these be valid? `2.392,39`
`2,292.39`

Comment: @Andreas thousand and decimal separators change depending on regions and/or countries. So technically both are valid, but I don't understand how would they be both valid in a single code. Oh well

Comment: That is my point. The question is unclear. @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: @Andreas it is clear *what* he wants to do, not *why* tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exclude them by adding a negative lookahead excluding them.

`(?!.*,.*\.*)` for the `2,292.39` search and `(?!.*\..*,*)` for the `2.392,39` search would do the trick

```
(?<!\d[- ]|[\d.,])-?[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:(?:[., ]\d{3})*|\d*)(?![\d%]|[- ][\d%])(?!.*,.*\.*)(?!.*\..*,*)
```

Test it here : https://regex101.com/r/XPgypx/4